# Google's login issue

Tags: support, status-completed, login, google

I was logging in to your sits using my Google account (my*hotmail*username@**live.com**) which was based on my hotmail address.

After a year, I decided to add GMail to my current Google account. But, when I created a GMail address **my*gmail*username@gmail.com**, I can no longer log in to my previous Stack Exchange account using Google.

I'm logging in successfully with my previous username (**my*hotmail*username@live.com**) but your sites always ask me to confirm and create a new account named **my*gmail*username@gmail.com**.

Please advice me if I can access my previous one or I should forget it?

Comment: @Vigbyor, I was logged in Google with my previous one then I asked for a GMail, then google assigned me a suggested email account where I do not know how Google merged them. But now, I can log in to my Google or GMail with both usernames which redirect me to my main Google's account but StackExchange does not recognize that my new GMail account is child of my main Google's account!

Comment: @Vigbyor, Thanks, I reviewed that but as I said I can no longer log in to my previous one to merge it with this new one! When I select Google login, it log in to my current new one :(

Comment: @Vigbyor, I tried but how I can **Edit my other user profile(s) "About Me" to say merge me as well**, when I can no longer log in into it :S

Comment: @Vigbyor, Thank you very much....I submitted the form. Please write your comment as answer to mark it if this solved the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill out [Account Merging Form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge). System will check your details merge them. Once merging is completed you can access your profile using any of email addresses.

Comment: Bingo...Stack Exchange merged them in only few hours...they're great!

Answer (score 5):

Your accounts are now merged, enjoy!

Comment: wow...how much fast stack exchange is! thanks a tone, you're perfect!